# HTML TextBox permanent text behind number

Tags: html, css, textbox, styling

I wanted to create a textbox for a unit measurement. E.g "1 Kg". 
I know can wrap a text just behind the textbox, but I wanted the unit to be inside the textbox itself. While the number can be changed, the unit behind it should stay just at the end of the textbox itself. Is there a way to do it? Possibly using CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: I would add the unit *after* the text field, not inside it. You're not making things better in any way (from a usability/UX point of view) by trying to add it inside. And appending it is way simpler, too.

Comment: I find kelvingram a rather surprising unit—maybe even more surprising than this desire to create a confusing user interface where a unit seems to be part of the input (and editable) but isn’t.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your input in a div, add your unit as a sub element to that div and position it above the textbox.

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/mayurexoyi/1/edit?html,css,output

HTML

```
  <div class="input_wrapper">
    <input type="text" value="20" />
    <div class="unit">KG</div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
input {
  font-size:14px;
  padding:10px 25px 10px 10px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
}

.input_wrapper {
  float:left;
  position:relative;  
}

.input_wrapper .unit {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top: 14px;
  color:#999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think THis will help you out .

**HTML :**

```
<div>

    <input type="text" />
    <label>kg</label>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
div{
  border:1px solid gray;
  width: 180px;
}
label{
font-family:arial;
 font-size:.8em;
}
input{
  border:none;
}
input:focus{
outline:none;
}
```

check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dym9702e/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <span contenteditable name="kgData" style='border: thin solid #000;'> Enter Value </span>
  <span contenteditable=false> Kg</span>
```

After submit, get kgData, then you can access that data on other page/ save it in db. See, if that helps.

Comment: Do you think I can have the span inside the textbox input?

Comment: No you can't add span to input box, but this span is acting like a text box.